# awk - change value

Tags: awk, gawk, mawk

File contains

```
TIMEOUT=abc
TIMEOUT=5
TIMEOUT=
xTIMEOUT=5
```

I need to change from

```
"TIMEOUT=5"
```

to

```
"TIMEOUT=9"
```

This command works.
But changes 4th line too, which is not desired

```
awk '$0 ~ "TIMEOUT=[:0-9:]" { $0 = "TIMEOUT=9" } {print}' file
```

And this command does not change anything

```
awk '$0 == "TIMEOUT=[:0-9:]" { $0 = "TIMEOUT=9" } {print}' file
```

What should I do? THANKS!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk '/^TIMEOUT=[:0-9:]/ { $0 = "TIMEOUT=9" } {print}' file
```

or even easier:

```
sed 's/^TIMEOUT=[0-9]/TIMEOUT=9/' file
```